# Content Height Based On Browser Viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, onload

I have some Javascript using JQuery to give my main content's container a height if it is smaller than the browser's viewport. This is to ensure the footer is always at the bottom of the page. Wen I call it like this, it works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var contentHeight = windowHeight - 325;
    if($("#content").height() <= contentHeight) {
        alert(contentHeight);
        $("#content").height(contentHeight+"px");
    }
});
```

But I want to declare it as a function so I can use it on the page resize event, but when I do that, it doesn't work. Here is the code I am trying to use:

```
function pageSizer() {
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var contentHeight = windowHeight - 325;
    if($("#content").height() <= contentHeight) {
        alert(contentHeight);
        $("#content").height(contentHeight+"px");
    }
}

$(document).ready(pageSizer());
$(window).resize(pageSizer());
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(pageSizer());
$(window).resize(pageSizer());
```

change to

```
$(document).ready(pageSizer);
$(window).resize(pageSizer);
```

You are invoking your functions instead of passing them as a reference which jQuery expects.